# how to check whether one of Claimants have Status 0 and assign Claim Status based on that

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Each Claim can have multiple Claimants. 
Claim is considered `'Open'` if at least one of those claimants have `ClaimantStatus = 0`

So I need to retrieve data on Claim Level (not Claimants) and Create column `ClaimStatus` that would indicate whether Claim is `Open` or `Closed`.

For each `ClaimID`, I need to check whether there is at least one Claimant have `ClaimantStatus = 0` (Open) and if this is true then column `ClaimStatus` should be = `'Open'`, otherwise should be = `'Closed'`

```
 declare @ClaimsTable table (ClaimID varchar(20))
 insert into @ClaimsTable values ('Claim1'),
                                 ('Claim2'),
                                 ('Claim3'),
                                 ('Claim4')

declare @ClaimantsTable table (ClaimID varchar(20),  ClaimantName varchar(50), ClaimantStatus int)
insert into @ClaimantsTable values ('Claim1','Claimant1',1),
                                   ('Claim1','Claimant2',0),
                                   ('Claim1','Claimant3',1),
                                   ('Claim2','Claimant2',0),
                                   ('Claim3','Claimant1',1),
                                   ('Claim3','Claimant2',1),
                                   ('Claim3','Claimant3',1),
                                   ('Claim4','Claimant1',0),
                                   ('Claim4','Claimant2',0)
--select * from @ClaimantsTable

select ClaimID,
        (select count (ClaimantName) from @ClaimantsTable ct where ct.ClaimID = c.ClaimID) as NumberOfClaimants,
    --below statement does not work correctly
        (select top 1 case when ClaimantStatus in (0) then 'Open' Else 'Closed' end as t from @ClaimantsTable ct where ct.ClaimID = c.ClaimID) as ClaimStatus
from @ClaimsTable c
```

Right answer should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `Exists` is what you're looking for

```
select ClaimID,
    (select count (ClaimantName) from @ClaimantsTable ct where ct.ClaimID = c.ClaimID) as NumberOfClaimants,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM @ClaimantsTable AS claimant 
                    WHERE claimant.ClaimID = c.ClaimID
                        AND claimant.ClaimantStatus = 0) 
        THEN 'Open' 
        ELSE 'Closed' END AS claimStatus
from @ClaimsTable c
```

Depending on your situation, you might also consider a grouped query. This can be more efficient by not needing to do two separate lookups for the count and status. This does require that there is at least 1 claimant for every claim.

```
SELECT
    claim.ClaimId
    ,COUNT(*) AS NumberOfClaimants
    ,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN claimant.ClaimantStatus = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Open' ELSE 'Closed' END AS claimStatus
FROM
    @ClaimsTable AS claim
    INNER JOIN @ClaimantsTable AS claimant
        ON claim.ClaimID = claimant.ClaimID
GROUP BY
    claim.ClaimID
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a simple `GROUP BY` is enough.
The `Claim` is open if at least one `Claimant` has ClaimantStatus = 0, we can use `MIN` to determine that. Here we rely on `ClaimantStatus` having only `0` and `1` values.

```
SELECT
    Claims.ClaimID
    ,COUNT(*) AS NumberOfClaimants
    ,CASE WHEN MIN(Claimants.ClaimantStatus) = 0 
        THEN 'Open' 
        ELSE 'Closed' 
    END AS ClaimStatus
FROM
    @ClaimsTable AS Claims
    INNER JOIN @ClaimantsTable AS Claimants ON Claimants.ClaimID = Claims.ClaimID
GROUP BY
    Claims.ClaimID
ORDER BY
    Claims.ClaimID;
```

Comment: Great simple way! Thank you